# Error: Code to find if a number is prime or not only works till 47

Tags: c++

I've written a c++ code for finding if a given number is prime or not, ot works fine till 47, but given the output as NO (for not a prime nunber) for prime numbers greater than 47.Please help.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x,t,z=2,y=1;
    cout<<"Enter the number: ";
    cin>>x;

    while (z<x )
    {
        t=x%z;
        z++;
        y=t*y;
    }

    if(y==0)
        cout<<"NO";
    else
        cout<<"prime";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Format it properly, debug it properly.

Comment: `y=t*y` looks like it might overflow pretty quickly. Maybe you could just use a `bool` instead.

Comment: If you print `t` every iteration you can see that you got an integer overflow. [See it in action](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36ee3d77db86aaae)

Comment: Why don't you use a simple `bool` with `if`/`else` for `y` to indicate whether a divisor was found? What is the purpose of the multiplication trickery?

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation leads to integer overflow pretty quickly. Since primes have no divisors except for 1 and themselves, `t = x % z` will be `z` all the time for primes. So for any `x` that is prime you are effectively calculating the factorial of `z-1`, which works for ~10 iterations before you get an overflow.

You don't need any multiplication here, once you you found a `z` where `x % z == 0` you can print "No" and return.

Example snippet:

```
while (z < x)
{
    if(t % z == 0) {
        std::cout << "No";
        return 0;
    }

    z++;
}

std::cout<<"prime";
```